# How to change the color in a final object3d with properties THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a object combined with a color and wireframe. I want to change the color base and color mesh material in the final object.
I use MeshBasicMaterial to MultiMaterialObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject` you will see that it creates the multi-material effect by creating child meshes of a parent object.

Use the following pattern to change the material colors:

```
var object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, materials );
...
object.children[ 0 ].material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
object.children[ 1 ].material.color.set( 0x00ff00 );
```

See the `THREE.Color` source code or docs for acceptable formats for setting colors.

three.js r.77

Comment: Thanks, I don't access to the children object.